# VBA code to bold selected words in table makes Excel sheet lag

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, lag, excel-tables

I have an Excel table with 1000 rows and 68 columns filled with mostly text data but also some columns with integers. The data is queried from a database using Power Pivot and once the data arrives, the Excel file works normally and is very fast, i.e. one can easily move through the table.

In my table, the first column has sentences in each cell and what I'm trying to do is to highlight certain words. I searched online and found a code that can do this and placed below. I got it from this website: https://www.computergaga.com/blog/format-specific-words-in-a-cell-using-vba/

What I notice is that once I let the code run and the words in the table are bold, scrolling through the table becomes extremely annoying due to the constant lagging of the sheet. I'm having a hard time understanding why this is the case, since bolding words in 1000 rows doesn't increase file size much and VBA variables should be cleared once they are out of scope, so the code should clear all references once it's done (thus not consuming memory). The full excel file is 1.8 MB after querying the data and there are no formula references in the table. I'm using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.21694) 32-bit.

Is the VBA code causing this lag somehow or does it have to do with the formatting itself or even power query? the table won't lag if I manually bold all words in all sentences.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
Sub HighlightText()
Dim rng As Range
Dim words As String
Dim NumChars As Long
Dim StartChar As Long
Dim rngChar As Long
Dim EndWords As Long
On Error Resume Next
words = InputBox("Please enter the word(s) to format", "Enter the words")
NumChars = Len(words)
    For Each rng In Selection
        rngChar = Len(rng)
        StartChar = InStr(1, rng, words)
        Do Until StartChar >= rngChar Or StartChar = 0
            EndWords = StartChar + NumChars
            If Mid(rng, StartChar - 1, 1) = " " Or StartChar = 1 Then
                If Mid(rng, EndWords, 1) = " " Or EndWords >= rngChar Then
                With rng.Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=NumChars).Font
                    .FontStyle = "Bold"
                    .Color = -16776961
                End With
                End If
            End If
            StartChar = InStr(EndWords, rng, words)
        Loop
    Next
   
End Sub
```

Comment: its possible that the For loop that you have is still running in the background. Try adding a `MsgBox` at the end of your code to know when the code execution is completed.

Comment: Consider using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before any processing is carried out. ensure it gets reset to True at the end of the sub and upon any error

Comment: It might be related to a problem in your workbook. If you copy your code to a new workbook and add the data from scratch (if possible - just make sure you don't copy the problem) it might work.

Comment: The code is definitely not running in the background. The issue presents itself after the code is done and while I scroll through the table to see the highlighted words.
I think it is related to Excel's difficulty in highlighting single words of text (or coloring them) in a corpus. As I scroll the screen, I suspect it has to somehow render them again and again, which makes moving around the sheet quite laggy.